# Excluding a subdomain from .htaccess mod_rewrite rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not too familiar with .htaccess files, and I'm trying to exclude a subdomain (something like `dev.example.com)` from the following rewrite rule that's already in place:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This rule prohibits anyone from just entering `example.com` or `http://example.com` and forces the desired presentation of the URL, `http://www.example.com`.

I've tried a few options of excluding a subdomain from this rewrite rule, but to no avail. Each of the directories on the site have their own .htaccess file, but it seems this one is still taking precedence. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The existing rule already excludes a subdomain. You just need to append a new condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can also get rid of regular expressions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dev.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The syntax can be found at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: This syntax seems like it'd work, but causes recursion errors. Any ideas?

Comment: However, your first example does indeed seem to work, using regular expressions...

Comment: Both snippets should be equivalent and work for me. I suggest you clean your browser's cache and try again.

Comment: Am I missing something here? This answer seems to include the dev subdomain in his rewrite, i.e. a call for dev.example.com will deliver www.example.com. I was under the impression the OP wants the opposite (as I do ;-)

Comment: @ChrisPink From [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond): *You can prefix the pattern string with a '!' character (exclamation mark) to negate the result of the condition, no matter what kind of CondPattern is used.*

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this could fit for you, but it is good practice to use apache virtualhosts configuration instead of `.htaccess` files. In that case, for the non-www -> www redirect, I usually use something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  example.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

That is generally safer than a `mod_rewrite` rule.

Comment: Since you are not actually matching anything, `Redirect` or `RedirectPermanent` should be enough.

Comment: I wrote that piece of configuration long time ago and then re-used it in several places as-is, so I don't remember exactly why I used `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`, but I guess that was the only way to preserve the full request path, instead of just redirecting to the fixed new URL. IE: `http://example.com/path/to/page.html` would redirect to `http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html`.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|www)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```